# self invoked function closures inJavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is a piece of code which makes number increment by one when clicking the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var incrementClickCount = (function () {
        var clickCount = 0;
        return function () {
            return ++clickCount;
        }
    })();
</script>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert(incrementClickCount());" />
```

What I don't know is that, I think we should get value "1" everytime when we click the button, so the sequences will be

**Step 1:** self invoked outer function call by self, the definition of inner anonymous function is stored in increment `incrementClickCount` variable.

**Step 2:** When click the button, call the inner anonymous function to change value of `clickCount` from 0 to 1, so we get 1 as input, fair enough.

**Step 3:** Here is the tricky part I don't understand here, when we click the button again. we actually call a new inner anonymous function, so the input should be 1 again, why it is 2 now? Just like this normal java or C# function:

```
public int getNumber()
{
   int clickCount = 0;
   return addNumber(clickCount);
}

public int addNumber(int number)

{
   return number++;
}
```

no matter how many times I call `getNumber()` function, I always get 1 rather than 1,2,3,4,5 ....

Comment: Each time the function is called you reset the clickCount value to 0, that is why it always shows 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when we click the button again. we actually call a new inner anonymous function

No.

The anonymous function is returned from the IIFE when the IIFE is parsed. That's why they are called *immediately invoked* function expressions. the `()` on the line `})();` invokes it (not `incrementClickCount()` which invokes the returned function).

**Every** time you click the button (including the first time), you call the **same** function that was returned (and assigned to `incrementClickCount`) at that time.

The IIFE never gets called again, so the line `var clickCount = 0;` never gets executed again.

Comment: But since IIFE has been called for the first time, the variable clickCount should be destroied, isn't it? just like a variable in an function, once the function has been called, there is no way the variable in the function can be accessed again?

Comment: "the variable clickCount should be destroied — No. The return value from the IIFE (the anonymous function)  is assigned to that variable. Nothing ever does anything with that variable except call that function. Nothing destroys it.

Answer (score 0):

At first `incrementClickCount` function call the IIFE returns the inner function which operates `clickCount` variable and increments it.
All further calls will be **ON** that inner function. So the `clickCount` variable is assigned `var clickCount = 0;` only once.
Consider the following output:

```
console.log(incrementClickCount);
// outputs the inner function definition    
return function () {
    return ++clickCount;
}

console.log(incrementClickCount());  // 1
console.log(incrementClickCount());  // 2
console.log(incrementClickCount());  // 3
```

Here is a good example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures

Comment: But since IIFE has been called for the first time, the variable clickCount should be destroied, isn't it? just like a variable in an function, once the function has been called, there is no way the variable in the function can be accessed again?

Comment: @slowjamsz11, No, *each closure has had its own environment ... The shared environment is created in the body of an anonymous function, which is executed as soon as it has been defined.* In your case `clickCount` variable is part of "*shared environment *"

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you clicking the button you are calling "incrementClickCount()" function.

but when the code actual run's for the first time, variable 'incrementClickCount' gets the value of returned function from the self invoking function.

so simply variable 'incrementClickCount' holds inner function inside it, as shown below.

```
incrementClickCount = function () {
            return ++clickCount;
        }
```

and clickCount value is available to this method due to closure. so it's incrementing it every time, instead of reseting the value.

as self invoking function is not getting called every time, due to that 'clickCount' is not getting reset to 0

Comment: But since IIFE has been called for the first time, the variable clickCount should be destroied, isn't it? just like a variable in an function, once the function has been called, there is no way the variable in the function can be accessed again?

Comment: @slowjamsz11 nope as that part of code is just executing once and after that it's in memory, as the variable is declared in global scope not inside the function scope.

Answer (score -1):

You should create the variable clickCount outside of the function and afterwards enable the onClick function to modify its value. Cheers.

Comment: `clickCount` is defined outside the (anonymous, returned) function, which is why the code works.